how to fix syntax error on using wget on Colab
wget 'https://dsmn.ml/files/d2-net/d2_tf.pth' -O models/d2_tf.pth

  File "<ipython-input-23-6839219d5fcc>", line 1
    wget "https://dsmn.ml/files/d2-net/d2_tf.pth" -O models/d2_tf.pth
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

syntax error. I need to learn how to fix. I have already installed and imported wget. Please someone help ...

I faced similar problem when downloading kenLM, you should add ! before wget on colab as follow , like !pip install:
!wget -O - https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm.tar.gz |tar xz

